# To find nearest rect elements within specified radius or distance of another rect element using D3

Tags: d3.js, svg

Is it possible to get all rect elements using another rect element ID, within a distance or a specified radius using D3. If it is possible, can someone share an example for the same. Following is my scenario:

[image]

Here, using the MainRect, i need to get all the ID's of small rects around the MainRect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the distance between to points by formula `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(X1 - X2, 2)+ Math.pow(Y1 - Y2, 2))`

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/tkL3dys5/1/) with example. Hover on red square to find little squares which center within a circle

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have one more doubt, suppose if I have added unique "id" for each small rects in the for loop such as .attr('id', 'std'+i) . How can i retrieve all those id's in mouseover event. https://jsfiddle.net/tkL3dys5/2/

Comment: updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/tkL3dys5/3/ change function `return`

Comment: or after filtering directly in `fill` function:
`.attr('fill', function() { console.log(d3.select(this).attr('id')); return 'green' });`